# The master report does not show basic subreport with Java Beans at Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, javabeans, jaspersoft-studio

I'm having trouble generating a basic report (master/subreport) with JavaBeans in Jaspersoft Studio.

I created *TestMainReport.jrxml* and *TestSubreport.jrxml*.

*TestMainReport.jrxml* contains two static text fields, labeled `"A Title"` in the title band and `"A Summary"` in the summary band.

*TestSubreport.jrxml* contains two static text fields, `"Subreport Title"` in the title and `"Subreport Summary"` in the summary band.

I've assigned JavaBeans Data Adapters to them, which are not used (although the JavaBean fields are being mapped in the master report. I just happened to not map them in the subreport since they are not used).

A subreport element has been added to the master report in the Summary band.

Both reports are well generated individually when I try to generate each one. However, the subreport static texts won't appear in the master report.

I was expecting that the subreport's static texts would appear in the master report.

What am I doing wrong?

***TestMainReport.jrxml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TestMainReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0d969cfb-66d2-442f-b7a4-5a9e1a40c3ae">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Customer Info Data Adapter"/>
    <field name="birthday" class="java.time.LocalDate">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[birthday]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="observacao" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[observacao]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="orderNumber" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[orderNumber]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="phone" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[phone]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="email" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[email]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="db07ac65-15f6-4190-b1db-9d445456f306"/>
                <text><![CDATA[A Title]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="215" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="08c03e87-2b15-4eb1-b404-b7dce6dfb890"/>
                <text><![CDATA[A Summary]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="560" height="150" uuid="c292246e-1ffa-4f08-a783-a0b05b28be76"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["TestSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

***TestSubreport.jrxml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TestSubreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d5dd9821-786d-4312-81c9-fd77f1abfb8a">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Customer Addresses Data Adapter"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4c9fdc83-4039-4eed-b593-448898853071"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Subreport Title]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4bb9ba45-548a-4e87-a543-472b0f960487"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Subreport Summary]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

***CustomerInfoDataSource.java***

```
package testdatasource;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomerInfoDataSource {

    public static Collection<CustomerInfo> getCustomerInfo() {
        List<CustomerInfo> info = new ArrayList<>();
        info.add(new CustomerInfo(1, "Mario", "mario@mario.com.br", LocalDate.now(), "14 912345678", "Observação Mario"));
        return info;
    }
}
```

***CustomerInfo.java***

```
package testdatasource;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class CustomerInfo {

    private final int orderNumber;
    private final String name;
    private final String email;
    private final LocalDate birthday;
    private final String phone;
    private final String observacao;

    public CustomerInfo(int orderNumber, String name, String email, LocalDate birthday, String phone, String observacao) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.observacao = observacao;
    }

    public int getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getObservacao() {
        return observacao;
    }
}
```

***CustomerAddressDataSource.java***

```
package testdatasource;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomerAddressDataSource {

    public static Collection<CustomerAddress> getCustomerAddresses() {
        List<CustomerAddress> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
        addresses.add(new CustomerAddress("Casa 1", "Rua Tal", "123", null, "Jardim Márcia", "Agudos", "17400-000", "Perto da caixa d'água"));
        addresses.add(new CustomerAddress("Casa 2", "Rua Tal", "456", null, "Jardim Márcia", "Agudos", "17400-000", "Perto da caixa d'água"));
        return addresses;
    }
}
```

***CustomerAddress.java***

```
package testdatasource;

public class CustomerAddress {

    private final String title;
    private final String street;
    private final String number;
    private final String complement;
    private final String bairro;
    private final String city;
    private final String cep;
    private final String referencePoint;

    public CustomerAddress(String title, String street, String number, String complement, String bairro, String city,
            String cep, String referencePoint) {
        this.title = title;
        this.street = street;
        this.number = number;
        this.complement = complement;
        this.bairro = bairro;
        this.city = city;
        this.cep = cep;
        this.referencePoint = referencePoint;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getComplement() {
        return complement;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public String getReferencePoint() {
        return referencePoint;
    }
}
```

**Output from TestMainReport.jrxml:**

[image: TestMainReport.jrxml output showing only two static text fields]

**Output from TestSubreport.jrxml:**

[image: TestSubreport.jrxml output showing only two static text fields]

Comment: @AlexK Sorry, I meant the 2 static text.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware the datasource needed to be set like that. I wasn't able to find a solution in the online documentation by myself -- would you have any tips in how to locate it in a search?

Comment: You are welcome :) `any tips in how to locate it in a search?` - 
It is hard to answer, if you know what to find - you have an advantage :). I think the good workflow for searching something about JR is: *"Look at JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide"* -> *"Look at Sample Reference (http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html)"* -> *"Look at JSS help"* -> *"Search at SO/community.jaspersoft.com"*.
I added some usefull links at my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is wrong?

You did not specify dataSource for subreport. Instead of this you have set *connectionExpression* (`<connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>`). The connection can help you in case *jdbc* based datasources (reports), but not at your case.

#### Solution1 - Using dataSourceExpression

You should specify datasource for subreport. You can declare subreport element like this:

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="560" height="150"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(testdatasource.CustomerAddressDataSource.getCustomerAddresses())]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["TestSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

In this case *CustomerAddressDataSource* class will be used for filling subreport.

#### Solution 2 - Using external definition of Data Adapter

You can export *Data Adapter* of subreport to the file and save it to the same folder as templates (if you don't want to specify path to data adapter file).

You can export *Data Adapter* definition with help of context menu at *JSS* (*Jaspersoft Studio*):

[image: Export function at JSS]

In your case - it will be *CustomerAddressesDataAdapter.xml* with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beanDataAdapter class="net.sf.jasperreports.data.bean.BeanDataAdapterImpl"><name>Customer Addresses Data Adapter</name><factoryClass>testdatasource.CustomerAddressDataSource</factoryClass><methodName>getCustomerAddresses</methodName><useFieldDescription>false</useFieldDescription><classpath>C:\somepath\library_with_beans.jar</classpath></beanDataAdapter>
```

You should specify this adapter at subreport with help of [*net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter) property. With help of this property you should specify name of file with *Data Adapter* definition (description), it can be name with path. At my case it will be: `CustomerAddressesDataAdapter.xml`.

The subreport template will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TestSubreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="CustomerAddressesDataAdapter.xml"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Subreport Title]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Subreport Summary]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

At master report the section with subreport will be:

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="560" height="150"/>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["TestSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

- as at previous case you don't need to specify connection.

As for the first solution the output result at *JSS* will be:

[image: The result via preview at JSS]

---

#### More information

- [Excel Data Adapter Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/exceldataadapter/index.html#exceldataadapter)
- [JSONQL Data Source Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsonqldatasource/index.html#jsonqldatasource)
- [Excel Data Adapter Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/exceldataadapter/index.html#exceldataadapter)
- [Using Data Adapters in Reports and Datasets](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v611/using-data-adapters-reports-and-datasets)
- [Data Adapters](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v611/data-adapters)